# Why does my 'time ago' filter work in chrome and not safari or firefox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I'm using this angular filter in my application to take a time stamp and convert it into 'time ago' time such as '3 hours ago'. I found the filter as a github gist and forked it to make it do conversions from UTC to the end user's local time. Now I'm can figure out why it only seems to work in chrome (note: I don't know if the original ever worked outside of chrome either). Safari and Firefox output 'in a long time' for all the times available from my application which span from a few minutes ago to a couple weeks ago. Any ideas?

```
app.filter('timeago', function () {

    //time: the time
    //local: compared to what time? default: now
    //raw: whether you want in a format of "5 minutes ago", or "5 minutes"

    return function (time, local, raw) {

        var timeZoneOffset = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()) * 60000;

        if (!time) return "never";

        if (!local) {
            (local = Date.now());
        }

        if (angular.isDate(time)) {
            time = time.getTime();
        } else if (typeof time === "string") {
            // convert string time to milliseconds
            time = new Date(time).getTime();
        }

        // convert UTC to local
        time = time - timeZoneOffset;

        if (angular.isDate(local)) {
            local = local.getTime();
        }else if (typeof local === "string") {
            local = new Date(local).getTime();
        }

        if (typeof time !== 'number' || typeof local !== 'number') {
            return;
        }

        var span = [],
            MINUTE = 60,
            HOUR = 3600,
            DAY = 86400,
            WEEK = 604800,
            MONTH = 2629744,
            YEAR = 31556926,
            DECADE = 315569260;


        var offset = Math.abs((local - time) / 1000);

        if (offset <= MINUTE)              span = [ '', raw ? 'now' : 'a minute' ];
        else if (offset < (MINUTE * 60))   span = [ Math.round(Math.abs(offset / MINUTE)), 'min' ];
        else if (offset < (HOUR * 24))     span = [ Math.round(Math.abs(offset / HOUR)), 'hr' ];
        else if (offset < (DAY * 7))       span = [ Math.round(Math.abs(offset / DAY)), 'day' ];
        else if (offset < (WEEK * 52))     span = [ Math.round(Math.abs(offset / WEEK)), 'week' ];
        else if (offset < (YEAR * 10))     span = [ Math.round(Math.abs(offset / YEAR)), 'year' ];
        else if (offset < (DECADE * 100))  span = [ Math.round(Math.abs(offset / DECADE)), 'decade' ];
        else                               span = [ '', 'a long time' ];

        span[1] += (span[0] === 0 || span[0] > 1) ? 's' : '';
        span = span.join(' ');

        if (raw === true) {
            return span;
        }
        return (time <= local) ? span + ' ago' : 'in ' + span;
    };

});
```

EDIT:

Here is an condensed example of how i'm using it in html and the format that my api is returning date strings in. If other's are not having issues it could be related to how date strings are converted to millisecond time.

Time from within an angular controller

```
$scope.time = "2014-07-04 23:04:12";
```

From the html

```
<span>{{ time | timeago }}</span>
```

Display from firefox

'in a long time'

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it could be the date / timezone handling. Have you considered using a cross browser date manipulation library like moment.js or dats.js?

Comment: Yes, if I can't find a good solution in the next day or so I will be trying out moment. I was hoping to keep this lightweight but it might be a pain to do so.

Comment: Can you give examples of how it is used in the HTML, and show what the output is in Firefox and why it is wrong?  I tried your code in firefox - works fine to me.

Comment: Added an edit with a usage example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Date.parse might be implementation dependent.   Based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse) and recommendation, I modified the custom parseDate function and verified that it works on IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

```
 app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
     // parse a date in yyyy-mm-dd format
     function parseDate(input) {
        var parts = input.split('-');
        var timeBits = parts[2].split(' ');
        var hms = timeBits[1].split(':'); 
        // new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
        return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, timeBits[0], hms[0], hms[1], hms[2]); // Note: months are 0-based
    }
    $scope.time = parseDate("2014-07-04 23:04:12");
    alert($scope.time);
  });
```

Comment: I hope this is helpful. I'm not sure if this was the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I just tested this out and it's now working for me in firefox, chrome, and safari. I'm on a mac tonight so I'll have to test out ie another day, but I don't foresee problems there.

Comment: To clarify incase other's are reading this... I replaced string to time conversion time = new Date(time).getTime() with the parseDate function supplied by pixelbits.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. For me it was the date format with time zone that wasn't working.

`"2014-07-04 23:04:12 GMT"` This wasn't working

`"2014/07/04 23:04:12 GMT"` This worked